# Xpages - getNextDocument() not accessing a Date field

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse, ssjs

The reason for the above error is because the 'FinishDate' field is empty, which is understandable. 
What I have been trying to do in the loop is replace any empty 'FinishDate' field with today's date.

'FinishDate' will be continuous until the activity has properly ended and that is when endDate will be generated and the 'FinishDate' field will be populated in the document.

I tried the below which works while looping through just the NotesDocument, but doesn't with NotesDocumentCollection:

```
               try {
                    var endDate:NotesDateTime = null;
                    if(!docEv.getItemValue("FinishDate").isEmpty()){
                        endDate = docEv.getItemValue("FinishDate").elementAt(0);
                    }else{
                        endDate = session.createDateTime(@Now());
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    print("endDate: " + e.toString())
                }
```

The 'else' statement is skipped each time it runs.

Below is the full code and the error block.

```
function getCalObj(){   
var viewEv:NotesView = database.getView("Diary");
var doc:NotesDocument = diaryDoc.getDocument();
var sUNID = doc.getUniversalID();
var dcEv:NotesDocumentCollection = viewEv.getAllDocumentsByKey(sUNID);
if(dcEv.getCount() != 0){
    var docEv:NotesDocument = dcEv.getFirstDocument();          
    var calendarData = '';      
    try {
        while (docEv != null) {
            var pattern = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
                try {
                    var calDate:NotesDateTime = docEv.getItemValue("QueryStartDate").elementAt(0);
                }catch(e){
                    print("calDate: " + e.toString());
                }
                try {
                    var endDate:NotesDateTime = null; //check if date is empty
                    if(!docEv.getItemValue("FinishDate").isEmpty()){
                        endDate = docEv.getItemValue("FinishDate").elementAt(0);
                    }else{
                        endDate = session.createDateTime(@Now()); // if endDate is null replace with todays date
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    print("endDate: " + e.toString())
                }                   
                try{
                    .........
                }catch(e){
                    print("Cal data error" + e.toString());
                }                           
            var tmpdocEv = viewEv.getNextDocument(docEv);
            docEv.recycle();
            docEv = tmpdocEv;
        }
    } catch(e) {
        print("DocEv Loop Error: " + e.toString()); //error, read below
        //DocEv Loop Error: Exception occured calling method NotesView.getNextDocument(lotus.domino.local.Document)
    };
};
```

}

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify the question. The error message in the question title relates to `getNextDocument()`, not accessing a Date field.

Comment: It's now amended, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through a NotesDocumentCollection but you use getNextDocument on the view and not the document collection. So change your line with getNextDocument to this:

```
var tmpdocEv = dcEv.getNextDocument(docEv);
```

Comment: That resolve the error - thanks, but still not accessing the Date field in the loop, which should then replace it with today's date if null.

Comment: Maybe check for null as well as `isEmpty()`. If the field does not exist, `getItemValue()` will be null, not an empty Vector. `hasItem()` would also check if the field exists. `getItem().getText()` will convert it to a text value, which could then be tested. It depends what value you're getting or whether there is another error that relates to getting a Date field (`getNextDocumentI()` doesn't deal with dates).

Comment: `getItemValue()` returns an empty `java.util.Vector` if item does not exist in document. It doesn't return null. So, the test should work.

Comment: It's now as it should. Not sure why it wasn't working before. I used only isEmpty(). Thanks for the help!